# Unbind Marshmallow transient object from database session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I'm using marshmallow_sqlalchemy library to build object from objects from schemas and then add the database. My Marshmallow and Sqlalchemy classes are defined as follows:

```
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema
from marshmallow import fields

class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    last_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    address = db.Column(db.Text)


class PersonSchema(ModelSchema):
    first_name = fields.String(allow_none=False)
    last_name = fields.String(allow_none=False)
    address = fields.String(allow_none=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        sqla_session = db.session
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address')
```

I have two session; `db.session` and `session_2`. Objects created through `PersonSchema` are attached to `db.session` by default. But I need to use `session_2` to add those objects to the database:

```
person_data = {'first_name': 'Bruno', 'last_name': 'Justin', 'Address': 'Street 34, DF'}
person = PersonSchema().load(person_data) # <Person (transient XXXXXXXXXXX)>
```

If I use `db.session` to add this object to db it will work fine:

```
db.session.add(person)
db.session.commit()
```

But, when I want to use `session_2` like this:

```
session_2.add(person)
session_2.commit()
```

I get an this error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Person at 0x7ff9193e27d0>' is already attached to session '2' (this is '4')`
which is expected as objects build with `PersonSchema` should be attached to `db.session` by default.

My question here is: Is there a way to unbind `person` from `db.session` to be able to use it with `session_2` without changing the definition of `PersonSchema`? Or maybe how to override the by default session when calling `.load`(I tried `.load(person_data, session=session_2)` and it didn't work)? What is the best way to avoid/fix this situation?

Comment: `session.expunge` will remove an instance from a session.

Comment: Already tried it and I got this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Instance <Person at 0x7ff9194b5bd0> is not present in this Session`

Comment: yes, I'am calling it like that: `db.session.expunge(person)`

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour from the description.  Can you provide a [mre]?